# Are there any examples of connected, dense total order spaces which are not separable?

Tags: general-topology

Like the title: Are there any examples of connected, dense total order spaces which are not separable?

I've still haven't made much progress with this. I know that they are order complete from being order dense and connected, but anything else escapes me.

Either an example or a refutation that such spaces exists would be most enlightening.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the book Counterexamples in Topology by Arthur Steen and Artur Seebach maybe can be helpful

Comment: @Gbes true, my examples are in it, but being an ordered space is not a thing they mention, only in the definition. So the back of the book tables wouldn't help except for finding non-separable connected normal spaces etc.

Answer (score 1):

$[0,1] \times [0,1]$ in the lexicographic order (and its induced topology), (so $(x,y) < (u,v)$ iff ($x < u$ or $x=u$ and $y<v$) ) is an example of a connected (and thus order dense) compact ordered space that is not separable.
Removing $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ creates a non-compact example.
Another non-compact (but countably compact) space is [the long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)) e.g.

A well-known theorem says that if $X$ is an ordered space that is connected (i.e. order dense and complete) and has no minimum nor maximum and is separable, then $X$ is homeomorphic (even order isomorphic) to the real line. This inspired the Suslin problem (whether we could weaken "separable" to ccc here, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin%27s_problem). And this gave rise to nice results in set theory and independence results. Both examples above are non-ccc such spaces. Under certain axioms (like $\diamondsuit$) we could use a Suslin line as a ccc example, which are even closer to the reals. In ZFC we cannot find such a space.

Comment: What does "CCC" stand for?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez countable chain condition: a space $X$ is ccc iff every pairwise disjoint family of non-empty open sets is at most countable. For metric spaces $X$ is ccc iff $X$ is separable.